# CSS, set style to div child

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div id="father">
  <div>Child div, needs height 100%</div>
</div>
```

How can I set a `height: 100vh` to the child div of id="father"? I can't add a class or id, it's a dynamic div created but an external js.

Comment: What is the "vh" affix on the height ?

Comment: `#father div { height: 100vh; }`...

Comment: @SPlatten [`vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vh) is equal to 1% of the height of the viewport's initial containing block.

Comment: or in js you can convert it as ```const vh_1 = Math.round(window.innerHeight / 100)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [child combinator selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator), `>`:

```css
#father > div { height: 100vh; }
```

Comment: the `>` is unnecessary. It means `select only first-level children` but there's only one level anyway

Comment: But I can't set that on a css file, because the child div isn't loaded yet, I need to set through javascript when document is ready

Comment: @JeremyThille It's necessary to prevent selecting any other element. For example, if there are other divs within the #father div, omitting it would select them

Comment: @pmiranda The rule will be applied whenever the page is loaded or changed.

Comment: @pmiranda Your image shows that you have in inline style being set on the child element. Also, CSS rules set in stylesheets don't show up as inline CSS. Are you able to remove the inline CSS? If not, you can try to increase the specificity of your CSS rule, or use the dreaded `!important` to override it.

Comment: `!important` was needed, thanks. Those inline styles are generated by Esri ArcGIS JS-API, , the whole divs are generated throught that API. Chrome did an update 4 days ago that crashes that ArcGIS API version (too old, 3.21), I have to do this customs css fixes...

Comment: @j08691 Allow me to disagree. As far as I know, `#father > div` will select all first-level `div` within `#father`. If it contains 5 divs, it will select them all (but not nested divs). If you want only the first one, you have to use `:nth-child(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the children of an element with the Child Combinator.

Access the child div by doing:

```
#father > div {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

For more information refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator